# Getting duplicate rows each time I make an entry in the Jtable using text fields

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

```
Below is my code:

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class SalaryCalculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    Container cn;
    JPanel pnlfirstPanel, pnlsecondPanel, pnlthirdPanel;
    JLabel lbfirstName, lblastName, lbaddress1, lbaddress2, lbzip, lbssn,
            lbsalaryAmount;
    JTextField tafirstName, talastName, taaddress1, taaddress2, tazip, tassn,
            tasalaryAmount;
    JButton btnsubmit, btncalculate;
    JTable tblgrid;
    String[] s = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Address 1", "Address 2",
            "Zip Code", "SSN", "Salary Amount" };
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Vector v= new Vector(7,7);

    public SalaryCalculator() {
        cn = getContentPane();
        cn.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        pnlfirstPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7, 2));
        cn.add(pnlfirstPanel);
        pnlsecondPanel = new JPanel();
        cn.add(pnlsecondPanel);
        //pnlthirdPanel = new JPanel();
        //cn.add(pnlthirdPanel);

        lbfirstName = new JLabel("            " + "First Name");
        // lbfirstName.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(lbfirstName);
        pnlfirstPanel.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        tafirstName = new JTextField();
        pnlfirstPanel.add(tafirstName);
        tafirstName.setSize(20, 30);

        lblastName = new JLabel("            " + "Last Name");
        lblastName.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(lblastName);
        talastName = new JTextField();
        talastName.setBounds(30, 50, 25, 20);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(talastName);

        lbaddress1 = new JLabel("            " + "Address 1");
        lbaddress1.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(lbaddress1);
        taaddress1 = new JTextField();
        taaddress1.setBounds(30, 50, 25, 20);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(taaddress1);

        lbaddress2 = new JLabel("            " + "Address 2");
        lbaddress2.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(lbaddress2);
        taaddress2 = new JTextField();
        taaddress2.setBounds(30, 50, 5, 5);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(taaddress2);

        lbzip = new JLabel("            " + "Zip Code");
        lbzip.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(lbzip);
        tazip = new JTextField();
        tazip.setBounds(30, 50, 25, 20);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(tazip);

        lbssn = new JLabel("            " + "SSN");
        lbssn.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(lbssn);
        tassn = new JTextField();
        tassn.setBounds(30, 50, 25, 20);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(tassn);

        lbsalaryAmount = new JLabel("            " + "Salary Amount");
        lbsalaryAmount.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(lbsalaryAmount);
        tasalaryAmount = new JTextField();
        tasalaryAmount.setBounds(30, 50, 25, 20);
        pnlfirstPanel.add(tasalaryAmount);

        btnsubmit = new JButton("Submit".toUpperCase());
        pnlsecondPanel.add(btnsubmit, -1);
        btnsubmit.addActionListener(this);


        tblgrid = new JTable(0, 7);
        JScrollPane j= new JScrollPane(tblgrid);    
        tblgrid.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        pnlsecondPanel.add(tblgrid.getTableHeader());
        pnlsecondPanel.add(tblgrid);
        for (int i = 0; i < tblgrid.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            TableColumn C1 = tblgrid.getTableHeader().getColumnModel()
                    .getColumn(i);
            C1.setHeaderValue(s[i]);
        }
        setSize(600, 550);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 550));

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DefaultTableModel dtm= (DefaultTableModel)tblgrid.getModel();
        TableModelEvent tme= new TableModelEvent(dtm);
        int row= tme.getFirstRow();
        int column = tme.getColumn();

        String  columnName= dtm.getColumnName(column);
        Object data=dtm.getDataVector();

            if (e.getSource()==btnsubmit){          
            int zip= Integer.parseInt(tazip.getText());
            int ssn= Integer.parseInt(tassn.getText());
            double salaryAmount= Double.parseDouble(tasalaryAmount.getText());

            v.add(tafirstName.getText());
            v.add(talastName.getText());
            v.add(taaddress1.getText());
            v.add(taaddress2.getText());
            v.add(zip);
            v.add(ssn);
            v.add(salaryAmount);
            dtm.addRow(v); // This is what i am using to enter data in table

            dtm.newDataAvailable(tme);
            tafirstName.setText(null);
            talastName.setText(null);
            taaddress1.setText(null);
            taaddress2.setText(null);
            tazip.setText(null);
            tassn.setText(null);
            tasalaryAmount.setText(null);
            tblgrid.transferFocus();
            System.out.println(v.capacity());           
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SalaryCalculator sc = new SalaryCalculator();

    }

}
```

Every time I click the submit button it adds a row in the table and also changes the previously added row. I tried putting an index in the vector but did not achieve any success.

Let me know what will be the solution to this as I am new to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you assumed that Vector(7,7) gives you two-dimensional structure. It doesn't.

When you declare `Vector v = Vector(7,7);` you get a vector that **can contain 7 objects and initial capacity of the vector is 7**.

The constructor of the Vector is

> [Vector(int initialCapacity, int capacityIncrement);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector(int,%20int)) // Constructs an
>   empty vector with the specified initial capacity and capacity
>   increment.

And these are methods to add data to the DefaultTableModel

```
void    addRow(Object[] rowData) //Adds a row to the end of the model.
void    addRow(Vector rowData)   //Adds a row to the end of the model.
```

Every row in DefaultTableModel is added with **a new Vector for each row**.

Add your data this way:

```
dtm.addRow(new Vector(            
    Arrays.asList(                // create a Collection from given args
        tafirstName.getText(),
        talastName.getText() ,
        taaddress1.getText() ,
        taaddress2.getText() ,
        zip                  ,
        ssn                  ,
        salaryAmount)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that resolves my issue and it seems working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared your `v` vector as a member variable of your `SalaryCalculator`, you are continually appending new data to your `v` Vector every time your submit button is clicked. Try create a new vector inside your `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  // ...

  if (e.getSource()==btnsubmit){
    Vector v= new Vector(7,7);
    v.add(tafirstName.getText());
    v.add(talastName.getText());
    v.add(taaddress1.getText());
    v.add(taaddress2.getText());
    dtm.addRow(v); 
    // ...
  }
```

This will ensure that a new vector containing information of a new "ta" is added to each row of your `DefaultTableModel` object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that resolves my issue and it seems working fine.:)

Comment: @Anupam Glad to hear. Please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer.